# Двухколоночный макет по центру страницы

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Доброго времени суток, мне понадобился двухколоночный макет по центру стр, вот накидал, в хроме не работает, кто знает почему?

```
<style>

/* ОСНОВНАЯ РАЗМЕТКА */
body { 
display: table; 
text-align:center; 
width: 100%;  
height: 100%; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px;
}

#main {
display: block;  
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0px; 
min-width: 800px;
max-width: 1000px;
*width: 800px;
height: 100%;
}

#header {
display: block;
width: 100%; 
background-color: red;
}

#helper {
display: block;
width: 300px; 
height: 100%;
background-color: #FCFBF8;
float:left;
}

#text {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
background-color: blue;
}

#footer {
display: block;
width: 100%; 
background-color: grey;
}

/* ОКОНЧАНИЕ ОСНОВНОЙ РАЗМЕТКИ */

</style>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>

<body>

<div id="main">

<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="helper">helper</div>

<div id="text">text</div>

<div id="footer">footer</div>

</div><!-- id="main" -->
    </body>
```

Comment: в хроме по центру не встает основная часть макета!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажите пожалуйста как Вы пришли в вёрстку? Судя по нескольким Вашим вопросам, наблюдается отсутствие общего понимание вёрстки.
Вот несколько замечаний:

1. Зачем div блоку делать display: block; если он по умолчанию такой?
2. Не используйте никогда старый стиль оформления для разметки ( font, center и т.д.), лучше используйте всю мощь CSS.
3. Если для фона элемента вы используете только background-color: цвет;, то лучше использовать более короткую запись background: цвет; Тоже самое можно сказать и про нулевые значения без обозначения единиц.

Кстати, если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, Вам надо, как минимум:

```
 #text{ float: left;}
 #footer { clear: both;}
```

А вообще, для выравнивания по центру используют свойство margin для блока-обрётки, в Вашем случае это:

```
#main {margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: я самоучка, так чуть-чуть, тут немного... я вообще менеджер по аренде дорожно-строительной техники, а сайт делаю в свободное время... 

спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: По собственному опыту, советую прочитать любую толковую книжку по CSS. Получаешь ответы на очень многие вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

вот рабочий вариант, обернуть содержимое в тег `<center>`, но насколько он правильный?

```
<center>    
<div id="main">    
<div id="header">header</div>    
<div id="helper">helper</div>    
<div id="text">text</div>    
<div id="footer">footer</div>    
</div><!-- id="main" -->    
</center>
```